# Apps to cast android videos to firestick

Tags: android, amazon

I have Amazon fire stick. And android phone. I am using tv cast for fire tv. But it gives issues sometimes. I heard of allconnect app. It's available on android, but I couldn't find on fire stick. Need suggestions for good paid or free appa to cast videos etc from mobile to firestick